# Anyone know of a scratch like program construction UI framework?

Tags: .net, mit-scratch

I quite like the drag and drop pluggable programming blocks in scratch   ( http://scratch.mit.edu/ )

I'd like to be able to get users to create their own mini scripts using the same kind of technique...

just wondering if anyone knows of anything similar I could utilise in .NET?  ideally in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) is something for you. You can [host the designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/cc835242(en-us).aspx) in your own application. So end-user can change the logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's not .NET, but have you looked at Alice? (http://www.alice.org/)

Answer (score 0):

yeah..... alice is quite interesting....   but scratch is like alice but simpler.  Targets a younger age group I think.

But the UI would be perfect for simple scripting

Answer (score 0):

StarLogo TNG could work, but it's designed for 3D simulations.